# Consumer VPN Service that allows multiple devices to network with each other

Tags: vpn, vpn-server

Typical consumer VPN services allow devices to connect to the internet through their VPN connection.

I am looking for a VPN service that in addition to providing internet access, gives me my own private network that I can connect multiple devices to.

The end would result would be my computer A and computer B could both connect to the VPN and then network with each other as if they were on a LAN.

I'm looking for the security of a hosted service, not to run my own VPN server

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not services – so this seems off-topic.

Comment: @izzy as they'd say in the biz, a hosted VPN is 'software as a service' (often with a local client!)

Comment: Well, you've got a point there. So speaking of the local client: what OS(es) must it support if needed? And what is the price margin (how much would you pay)?